# Filtering callback passed arguments

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I need to use third party library and there is function which I need to pass **myCallBack** function which will be later called with arguments **argA** and **argB** respectively.

The problem is that **myCallBack** needs only argB. What would be correct way for doing this? I think most people would do it like this:

```
libraryExample.asyncFunc((argA, argB) => {
    myCallBack(argB);
});
```

With arrow functions, I tried following:

```
libraryExample.asyncFunc((argA, argB) => myCallBack(argB));
```

It seems working and this will also work:

```
libraryExample.asyncFunc((argA, argB) => myCallBack(argB.propertyName));
```

but is that valid syntax? Any other ideas?

Comment: Well do you want to `return` the results of `myCallBack(…)` to `asyncFunc` or not? That's the difference between #1 and #2.

Comment: Why wouldn't accessing `.propertyName` be valid syntax? But no, obviously this does something different than not accessing the property.

Comment: No, I don't need the return value of myCallBack.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
 libraryExample.asyncFunc((_, argB) => myCallBack(argB));
```

as that makes clear that the first argument is not needed, and the return value of `myCallBack` gets passed back to the caller.

Comment: Thats probably good idea to mark the unwanted arg. What you mean the return value of myCallBack gets passed back to the caller?

Comment: @john in your first snippet no matter what `myCallBack()` returns, calling `(argA, argB) => { myCallBack(argB); }` will evaluate to `undefined`